# Memory keep increasing with custom view

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Please take a look at my code

```
protocol CustomViewDelegate: class {

}
class CustomView: UIView {
    var button: UIButton! = {
        //setup
        }()
    weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?
}

class controller: UIViewController {
    var customView: CustomView! = {
        //setup
    }()

    private func setup() {
        customView.button.addTarget(self, action: "actionForButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
}
```

At first, I think this code won't cause any problem because I already set `weak` for delegate. Furthermore, I've been coding like this for more than a year and it works just fine.

But I was wrong, these line of code does cause memory increasing and it surprised me.

Why does this happen in swift, it works fine in objective-C ?
Is there any better solution for this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Method `addSubview(_:)` ([developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:)) establishes a strong reference, therefore your `var button: UIButton!` and `var customView: CustomView!` should be `weak` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are adding it as subview many times.